# Jetson xavier NX with buzzer

Tags: python, gpio, jetson-xavier

I'm trying to connect a buzzer to jetson xavier NX through Jetson.GPIO library in python, I tried a lot and I couldn't seem to get it right, I also made a lot of research about this and couldn't find any useful information.

Can you help me?
I'm trying to connect a buzzer to GPIO so I can control when it beeps and when it stops through python.

Thank you for your time!